# ExcelJs adding common style function with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, exceljs

I am trying to add a function that would apply styles dynamically to rows.

```
  import ExcelJS, { Row, Column, Style }  from 'exceljs';
    const addCommonStyles = (row: Row , applyRowStyles: string[]) => {
        const styles: Style = {
            font: { name: 'Calibri', family: 4, size: 14, bold: true, color: excelExportStyles.BLACK_COLOR },
            fill: { type: 'pattern', pattern: 'solid', fgColor: { argb: `FF${excelExportStyles.WHITE_COLOR}` } },
            border: { left: { style: 'thick', color: excelExportStyles.BLACK_COLOR } },
            alignment: {},
            protection: {},
            numFmt:'',
        }
        Object.keys(styles).forEach((style)=>{
        if(applyRowStyles.includes(style)){
            row[style as keyof Style] = styles[ style as keyof Style ] as any;
        }
    });
      return row;
    }
```

Usage:

```
addCommonStyles(row, ['font','border']);
```

While this works, I want to avoid using type `any`.

I am a bit new to Typescript and unable to wrap my head around how I can get this working without adding `any`